# react-native-camera is not working getting error undefined is not an object (evaluating CameraManager.Aspect)

Tags: react-native

Steps to Reproduce :-

1. npm install react-native-camera.
2. include this package in component 
   1). import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
3. Then i am building react-native run-android.
4. build is successfull but i am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating CameraManager.Aspect) in the emulator.

Comment: Don't you need to destructure with `import { Camera } from ...` instead? According to the [Github](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) you do.

Comment: I tried using that but still not working

Comment: you need to run react-native link react-native-camera after npm install

Comment: Build is faling getting error in build.gradle file my build.gradle file is like this

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

Comment: allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

Comment: I think there might be version problem because in some examples online it was working but when i try to do the same it is not working can anybody help me from this.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has not done this step, do more!

Please Add this into your gradle file

```
android{
...
 defaultConfig {
...
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

}
AND also add the below dependency in your gradle

```
dependencies {
```

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }
This will definitely solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 reasons.

1 .If you use simulator then its ok... You can not use camera on simulator.

2. If you test that in real phone make sure that you have permissions for camera.

Comment: I also used simulator and checked but still the issue is same

Comment: I mean when u use simulator you can not us Camera... Try in real device.

Comment: I do things like that with Expo.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution i use react-native-image-picker package
Camera Feature is working .

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker